# generar informe de cristal basado en la selección del cuadro combinado en vb

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Codigo en Visual Tengo formulario con 1 Boton y 1 Combobox que tiene items cargados de diferentes Reportes. Al seleccionar el combobox pulso boton para buscar el reporte. pero me manda error de memoria y indica el reporte no existe El codigo es:

Private Sub BtnTipoReporte_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnTipoReporte.Click

```
    Dim rtp As New Reporte_Pagos


    If ComboReporte.Text = "REPORTE DE PAGOS" Then
       'CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reporte_Pagos.rtp"

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rtp
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End If
```

Abre el crystal report view pero al cargar otro reporte vuelve a repetir el primer reporte

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te faltan las condiciones ELSEIF para los demás reportes, algo asi:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Dim rtp as CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

rtp = New Reporte_Pagos

If ComboReporte.Text = "REPORTE DE PAGOS" Then
      
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rtp
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

Elseif ComboReporte.Text = "REPORTE 2" Then
        CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = rtp
        CrystalReportViewer2.Refresh()
EndIf
```

Comment: ¿Eso explica el error de memoria?